# Use the rules of inference to prove p ∧ s, given the following premises?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Did I answer this question correctly? I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do?

Use the rules of inference to prove p ∧ s, given the following premises. Write your solution as a numbered sequence of statements. Identify each statement as either a premise, or a conclusion that follows according to a rule of inference from previous statements. In that case, state the rule of inference and refer by number to the previous statements that
the rule of inference used.
(1) ¬r
(2) s
(3) q ∨ r
(4) q → p

My answer:

(1) ¬r (premise)
(2) s  (premise)
(3) q ∨ r (premise)
(4) q → p (conclusion)

Comment: No, that's not the argument.  All those are the premises.  You are to design your own argument, using those four premises along with **rules of inference**, to demonstrate the conclusion that $p\wedge s$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Fill in the blanks.

By (1), we conclude (5) R is __ .

By (5) and (3), we conclude (6) Q is __.

By (6) and (4), we conclude (7) P is __.

By (7) and (2), we conclude the desired result.